# Is the implementation or documentation of the System.Drawing.Drawing2D Matrix incorrect?

Tags: c#, .net, matrix, system.drawing, affinetransform

When you get the elements for the Array (the coefficients) and then use them in the standard fashion defined for linear algebra to multiply the matrix with a vector, you get a different answer than if you call the TransformPoints method for the Matrix.  I believe this is an error in either the Microsoft documentation or in the implementation.

That is, given the matrix M and the Point a, where M(a) is the result of calling M.TranformPoints(a)

M(a).x  **!=**  M11*ax + M12*ay + dx

and

M(a).y  **!=**  M21*ax + M22*ay + dy

However, looking at all the definitions I could find for multiply a matrix and a vector and for matrix notation (i,j) where i is the row and j is the column the above equations should be equal.
The only way you get the correct answer is if you switch the positions of M12 and M21 above.  However, if you do this the equations no longer agree with the standard notion and common usage of multiplying a matrix and a vector (or point).

See the more detailed explanation below with the MSDN documentation and a sample program I wrote.

### The documentation for the Constructor taking six Singles is [Matrix Constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d0616edf(v=vs.110).aspx)

Matrix Constructor(Single, Single, Single, Single, Single, Single)

Syntax:

public Matrix(
    float m11,
    float m12,
    float m21,
    float m22,
    float dx,
    float dy)

Parameters:

- m11 Type: System.Single The value in the first row and    first
  column of the new Matrix.
- m12 Type: System.Single The value in
  the first row and second column of the new Matrix.
- m21 Type:    System.Single The value in the second row and first
  column of the new    Matrix.
- m22 Type: System.Single The value in the second row and    second
  column of the new Matrix.
- dx Type: System.Single The value in    the third row and first column
  of the new Matrix.
- dy Type:    System.Single The value in the third row and second
  column of the new    Matrix.

### The documentation for the Elements Property is: [Matrix.Elements Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.drawing2d.matrix.elements(v=vs.110).aspx)

- Gets an array of floating-point values that represents the elements
  of this Matrix.

Property Value

- Type: System.Single[]
- An array of floating-point values that represents the elements of
  this Matrix.

Remarks: The elements m11, m12, m21, m22, dx, and dy of the Matrix are represented by the values in the array in that order.

---

I wrote a sample program to confirm what I was seeing and it is shown below.  Note, that using the elements (matrix coefficients) in equations only works if I transpose m12 and m21 which does not agree with general matrix (i,j) (row, column) notation and multiplication.  My program is below.  My questions is whether Microsoft's documentation/implementation is wrong? Am I overlooking something or doing something wrong?

In my code the X,Y values for PointsA[0] only equals the X and Y values for x1, y1 where the m12 and m21 element values are transposed in the equation.  Code is below:

```
  class Program
   {
      static void Main(string[] args)
      {
         var pointsA = new Point[1];
         pointsA[0].X = 1;
         pointsA[0].Y = 1;
         var pointsB = new Point[1];
         pointsB[0].X = 1;
         pointsB[0].Y = 1;

         // Transform PointsA using Matrix
         Matrix m = new Matrix(1,1,0,1,0,0);
         m.TransformPoints(pointsA);

         // Transform PointsB using Elements.
         var elements = m.Elements;
         var m11 = elements[0];
         var m12 = elements[1];
         var m21 = elements[2];
         var m22 = elements[3];
         var dx  = elements[4];
         var dy  = elements[5];

         var pointB = pointsB[0];

         var x = m11 * pointB.X + m12 * pointB.Y + dx;
         var y = m21 * pointB.X + m22 * pointB.Y + dy;

         // Correct answer but had to transpose positions of m12 and m21 from what would be the normal matrix x vector multiplication.
         var x1 = m11*pointB.X + m21*pointB.Y + dx;
         var y1 = m12*pointB.X + m22*pointB.Y + dy;
      }
   }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes the correct answer is this:

```
var x1 = m11*pointB.X + m21*pointB.Y + dx;
var y1 = m12*pointB.X + m22*pointB.Y + dy;
```

But there's no error. The description of the matrix gives us this, 3 rows, 2 columns (3x2):

```
[m11 m12]
[m21 m22]
[dx  dy ]
```

When multiplied by the vector which must be 1 row, 3 columns (1x3):

```
[ax ay 1][m11 m12]
         [m21 m22]
         [dx  dy ]
```

You get the 1x2 result:

```
[ax * m11 + ay * m21 + dx , ax * m12 + ay * m22 + dy]
```

[This documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.drawing2d.matrix(v=vs.110).aspx) demonstrates that they use a row-major matrices and row vectors rather than the more common mathematical convention of column-major and column vectors.

[image: 3x3 matrix]

So in actual fact the matrix represents a 3x3 so that they can be chained together but this makes no difference as the final column is always `0 0 1` in an affine transformation which is all this class can represent.

```
[ax ay 1][m11 m12 0] = [ax * m11 + ay * m21 + dx , ax * m12 + ay * m22 + dy , 1]
         [m21 m22 0]
         [dx  dy  1]
```

## Plus side to this order

If I have a point (P) and I want to Translate (T) and then Scale (S) I find it more readable with this notation:

```
transformedPoint = P*T*S
```

Rather than:

```
transformedPoint = S*T*P
```

And so code that uses this order will also be more readable.

Comment: Weston,  Do you know why Microsoft would adopt a vector*Matrix notation versus a Matrix*vector notation.  Every example, book, and online resource always shows Matrix multiplication with a vector as M*v not v*M?  I think your answer is probably right, I just wish their documentation noted this somewhere so it was not so confounding and confusing.

Comment: @eesh, I can't say for certain 'why', but one possible rationale is that if if you want to treat your vectors as 'row vectors' then you need to use multiplication on the right to perform transformations.  Direct3D (another MS technology) used row-major ordering for storage and also used multiplication on the right.  OpenGL (a different graphics technology) used column-major ordering and multiplication on the left.  Mathematical convention is to use column vectors and multiply on the left, but I think that's largely motivated by it being more compact to write.

Comment: I also can't say why, but if you look at the documentation here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.drawing2d.matrix(v=vs.110).aspx it shows they use the row major matrices and row vectors.

Comment: I am pretty sure that I had looked at this documentation for the matrix class before and the explanation that you added to the answer did not exist when I looked into this a few weeks ago.  Of course it may just be I missed it.  In any case I am glad the documentation is there now and this pretty much definitively answers my question.  Thank you Weston.  Apparently I cannot award the bounty for another 8 hours.  But it is pretty much yours unless somebody blows away your answer.

Answer (score 0):

The standard Cartesian coordinate system is [right-handed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_coordinate_system#Orientation_and_handedness), i.e. you have to turn a vector pointing in x-direction counterclockwise by 90 degrees in order to make it point in y-direction. The coordinate system used in `System.Drawing` is left-handed, because the y-axis points downwards. This might explain the discrepancy.

```
  |    x
--+----->
  |           Coordinate system used by System.Drawing
 y|
  v
```

Answer (score -1):

The System.Drawing.Drawing2D.Matrix is showing us that multiply a vector that is Transposed first by transformation matrix is same as transformation matrix transposed multiply by vector.[image]